# VBA Replacing variable ranges that have values > 0 depending on cell value of the first column in row

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, so I feel like I am getting closer but I am running in to an object error. I am trying to replace old values in an excel sheet with the new charge values. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

This is an example of the type of table I might start out with.

[image]

This is what I want it to look like after I run the VBA

[image]

Here is what I have so far.

```
 Sub Testing()
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim UpdateRng As Range
  Dim SelectRng As Range
  v = 2

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ' Get count
  NumRows = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  Range("B2").Select
  ' Cycle through loop
  For x = 1 To NumRows
  
    Set SelectRng = Range("C" & v & ":" & "F" & v) 'Set range
    
    If "A" & v.Vaule = " " Or v.Value = "" Then GoTo NextV
    
        For Each UpdateRng In SelectRng
            If UpdateRng.Value > 0 Then
                UpdateRng.Value = Range("A" & v).Value
            End If
        Next
NextV:
        v = v + 1
       Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `v` is numeric and has no `.Value`. You should be using `x` in your loop. And `Range("A" & x).Value`

Comment: So any value in the right hand side has to be replaced with the value in the first column? Note too `v.Vaule`. You can dispense with the `Goto` too.

Comment: Thank you for your help @BigBen I was able to get working with the v variable. I know I should be able to get it working with the x variable, but not sure how to get it to start on the right row.

Comment: In future I would advise to have store types within a single column rather than across multiple columns (i.e. unpivot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and declare all variables.
- Avoid using `GoTo` as that generally creates spaghetti code.
- [Use `End(xlUp)` to determine the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).
- [Avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).
- [Use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

```
Sub Testing()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    With ws
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        With ws
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
                .Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Replace "*", .Range("A" & i).Value
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that this considers all values when replacing, not just values greater than 0. Though I *think* the `>0` check is essentially checking if the cells in columns `C:F` are not empty.

Comment: That top part of your answer should be given, boilerplate, to all new users.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this. However, Bigben's is much cleaner.

```
Sub Testing()
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim UpdateRng As Range
  Dim SelectRng As Range
  v = 2

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ' Get count
  NumRows = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  Range("B2").Select
  ' Cycle through loop
  For x = 1 To NumRows
  
    Set SelectRng = Range("C" & v & ":" & "F" & v) 'Set range
    
    If Range("A" & v).Value = " " Or Range("A" & v).Value = "" Then GoTo NextV
    
        For Each UpdateRng In SelectRng
            If UpdateRng.Value > 0 Then
                UpdateRng.Value = Range("A" & v).Value
            End If
        Next

NextV:
        v = v + 1
       Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```